# (sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in) is there a syntax error that I'm missing?

Tags: php, sql-server

I need to get a report based on a datetime column which is actually the average of another column for each hour of the day ,
so i wrote a query and put it in a for loop so i can change the hour variable for comparison, and after that i wanna echo it so i can use it to create a line chart !

i have something similar in the same page and it's working fine but this one ain't .

I'm using `PHP 7` with sql Server 2016

here's the code :

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $date_hour ; $i++)
{
    $j = $i-1;
    $query = Query("SELECT AVG(sp_efficiency_r) FROM sp_data_records WHERE sp_detail_id_r =$key_id and sp_sent_time_r >= '2018- $date_month - $date_day   $j  :00:00.000' and sp_sent_time_r <= '2018-$date_month-$date_day   $i:00:00.000'");
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query,SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
    echo $row[0].",";
    if ($flag1 = true) {
        $flag1 = false;
        $date_day++;
    }
    elseif ($flag = true) {
        $date_day = 1;
        $flag = false;
    }
}
```

I used anything i could find on the internet about concatenating, things like '`{$data}`' and `. $data .` are showing the same error to me .

I'm a rookie in this so i'd be glad if you help me with as much details as possible . TNX

Comment: Use $query = sqlsrv_query(...). And set parameters for that sqlsrv_query() call.

Comment: I wrote a function for the , as u can see in the code it's 'Query' which is sqlsrv_query($conn,$stmt)

Comment: Can you exec this: print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true) after $query = Query(...); and post the result? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error `"sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"` means that `sqlsrv_query()` returns false instead of statement resource. In your case I think that the reason is wrong SQL statement.

The problem might be the `date` columns. You need to pass string values as dates using unambiguous date\time format, in your case `'2010-01-27T15:33:13.343'`. I also suppose that `$date_month`, `$date_day` and `$key_id` are defined and are numbers.

So, you can try with this:

```
...
for ($i = 1; $i <= $date_hour ; $i++) {
    $j = $i-1;
    $sql = 
        "SELECT AVG(sp_efficiency_r) 
        FROM sp_data_records 
        WHERE 
            (sp_detail_id_r = ".$key_id.") AND 
            (sp_sent_time_r >= '".sprintf("2018-%02d-%02dT%02d:00:00.000", $date_month, $date_day, $j)."') AND 
            (sp_sent_time_r <= '".sprintf("2018-%02d-%02dT%02d:00:00.000", $date_month, $date_day, $i)."')
        ";
    $query = Query($sql);
    # Next 2 lines are just for test
    echo "Possible error message: ";
    print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
    echo $row[0].",";
}
...
```

Comment: @arian.s Strange, it works in my test case. Can you post values for $date_month, $date_day and $key_id, and how exactly are you calling sqlsrv_query(). Thanks!

Comment: with the previous code there was 24 errors ! all the same , now it's five , i guessed that it's a logical problem coming from wrong calculations , but even if the calculations are wrong the query shouldn't fail ! should it ?

Comment: the value $date_hour is the hour of the latest record with a specific id , so as the others , the loop is to increment the value of it from 00 until $date_hour, eg. $date_hour = 5 ! then I'd be wanting the avg from 00 to 01 , 01-02 , ... , 04 to 05 .

Comment: @arian.s I've updated the answer. If you want to check the logic, leave only SQL statement execution.

Comment: I've found it , tnx a moon